# Como pasar variable de javascript a php

Tags: php, javascript

espero se encuentren muy bien.

Tengo el siguiente código:

El javascript lo que hace es traer una variable de acuerdo a otra variable ya seleccionada anteriormente, ya logre hacer que me imprima la variable por medio del id, pero como haria para imprimir esa variable que me imprime en el id='cbx_equipo' en php.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
                $("#cbx_localidad").change(function () {
                    $("#cbx_localidad option:selected").each(function () {
                        id_md = $(this).val();
                        $.post("includes2/getDatos4.php", { id_md: id_md }, function(data){
                            $("#cbx_equipo").html(data);
                            
                        });            
                    });
                })
            });
            
        </script>

<table>
<tr>
<td><font color="#000">Equipo:</font></td>
    <td><select name="cbx_equipo" id="cbx_equipo" style="width:250px;border:1px solid #04467E;background-color:#DDFFFF;color:#2D4167;font-size:18px" onchange="this.style.width=200">
 
 
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Estoy buscando hacer que la variable id='cbx_equipo'

La imprima en php para poder usarla en otra consulta que necesito hacer.

```
echo $variable = id='cbx_equipo';
```

de que forma se puede hacer esto?

Cualquier ayuda me podría ser de gran utilidad, muchas gracias.

Comment: Asumiendo que el código JS se está ejecutando en un cliente en una aplicación web y el código php en un servidor web, vas a tener que hacer una petición AJAX a tu servidor web con el valor para que la puedas recibir y procesar en un script php.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que podrías hacer es un AJAX, lo que hace esta herramienta es que mantiene la comunicación asíncrona con el servidor en segundo plano, mientras se está ejecutando en el cliente

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET OR POST',
  url: 'La ruta que lleva al método en el quieres mandar la info',
    data: { // Si es POST, mandas tus variables obtenidas con JQuery o Javascript
        'value': var
    },
    success: function success(data) {
    //Lo que quieres que haga si todo sale bien
        console.log("Success", data);
    },
    error: function error(data) {
    //Lo que quieres que haga si algo falla
        console.log("Error", data);
    }
});
```